# Laravel PHPunit test return 500

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-7, testcase

For Laravel API I have write PHPUnit test but whenever I will run this I received a 500 error as below

```
1) Tests\Feature\CompanyTest::orgTest
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 500.
```

Actually the issue is I have created 2 separate `subdomains in my local for running the web (web.local) and API (api.local) environment`. Whenever calling the API from web domain it returns a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` hence I have added a **cors middleware** in laravel. Because of this cors middleware whenever I run the PHP unit test received below error in laravel log,

> local.ERROR: Cannot modify header information - headers already
> sent by (output started at
> /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:119)
> {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Cannot modify header
> information - headers already sent by (output started at
> /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:119) at
> /app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php:18)

**My Cors Middleware code as below**

> Middlaware/cors.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://web.local');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, PUT');
        return $next($request);
    }
```

> Kernel.php

**$middleware array**

```
\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
```

**$routeMiddleware array**

```
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

I have also tried with Laravel 7 CORS support By adding below code in **Config\cors.php** file but no success.

> Config\cors.php code

```
return [    
    'paths' => ['api/*'],    
    'allowed_methods' => ['POST, PUT'],    
    'allowed_origins' => ['http://web.local'],    
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],    
    'allowed_headers' => ['Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin'],    
    'exposed_headers' => [],    
    'max_age' => 0,    
    'supports_credentials' => false,    
];
```

I have googled the error and tried many solutions but unable to succeed. Anyone, please let me know whats the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Laravel 7 supports CORS out of the box, hence, you don't need your own middleware for that https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/releases#laravel-7

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/cannot-modify-header-information?page=0

Comment: @Tony I have tried the same but no success. I have updated that code in my question

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem just now, and I solved it by installing php-sqlite, depends on your php version mine was:

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite3`

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here because of another cors problem :D but the answer to your question is that you cannot add `header` unless it is nothing printed to stdout, not even a new line. So after the first output, PHP will never accept any new header because it will be already processed and it is not possible to modify them, that is why you are receiving that error.

in order to add these headers you may add them to the response object:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://web.local');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, PUT');

       return $response;
    }
```

I hope that helps you or anyone comes here from google :D